# fwrite failing with segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c

here's my code ...I have a function...

```
void openPageFile(filehandle *fHandle) {


   FILE *fptr;
     opening file 
     initialise fields in fHandle
     fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_SET);
     fwrite(fHandle, PAGE_SIZE, 1, fptr);

   }
```

I'm calling this from another function... in this way

```
  void test(){

     filehandle fHandle;
   openPageFile(&fHandle);

    }
```

and fhandle struct is ...

```
  typedef struct FileHandle {


     char *fileName;
     //some other fields

   } fileHandle;
```

this is giving me different results.

> on windows system, its working fine.
>   on ubuntu 12.04, it doesn't give any error but it doesnt write any data. 
>   on ubuntu 13.10, it gives me seg fault in fwrite line.

I've used valgrind to check for memory leaks and here's my stack trace.

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3118==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4051EB
==3118==    at 0x4EB44A0: __GI_mempcpy (memcpy.S:166)
==3118==    by 0x4EA4EFD: _IO_default_xsputn (genops.c:463)
==3118==    by 0x4EA3611: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1356)
==3118==    by 0x4E9973C: fwrite (iofwrite.c:43)
```

i can't figure out exactly whats going on...

Comment: What is PAGE_SIZE? If it's bigger than a FileHandle, then that's why.

Comment: it is 4096 it should be enough.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. You try to write 4096 bytes starting at fHandle, but there might not be 4096 bytes to write.

Comment: HI. I observed few things and would like to share. I can write any amount of data irrespective of size unless that causes buffer overrun.
 technically, PAGESIZE is working fine. my problem was with allocating memory to struct.
changed  
filehandle fHandle;
   openPageFile(&fHandle);
to 
 filehandle *fHandle=(FileHandle *)malloc(PAGE_SIZE);
   openPageFile(fHandle); and fixed. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Yes, that does work. It does, however, ignore good engineering principles (mainly in that it's unusual and therefore harder to understand). There's also a small chance the uninitialized memory might contain sensitive information, which gets leaked into the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the constant `PAGE_SIZE` with `fwrite`, instead use `sizeof(*fHandle)`. Separately write or seek to add any padding necessary if you need to match `PAGE_SIZE` in the output.

(I'm not altogether sure how much sense it makes to write the `struct FileHandle` in this manner, though, since you'll be writing, e.g., the memory address at `char *fileName` rather than the file name string. You would need to write the fields separately in that case.)

Comment: I'll try that. I was keeping my block size fixed. It was large enough. I'll try using sizeof(*fHandle) instead.

Comment: changing the size fixed my problem. Thank you